# #define efficiency in C

Tags: c, performance

I'm new to C and was wondering which is the more efficient or preferred way to program the following:

Option A:

```
#define flag true

void Foo()
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < veryBigNumber; i++)
   {
      if (flag)
         doSomething1();
      doSomething2();
   }
}
```

Option B:

```
#define flag

void Foo()
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < veryBigNumber; i++)
   {
#if defined(flag)
         doSomething1();
#endif
      doSomething2();
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it with an optimising compiler? 5 bucks says both will be of the same speed. Oh why speed, even the binaries might look identical :)

Comment: Even if there is no performance difference, the source codes are semantically different. And since source code is as important as it's performance you should pick the one that expresses more accurately your intention.

Comment: @legends2k, I'm compiling it in Cuda, since I'm new to C/Cuda I'm not sure how/if it is optimizing the C code.

Comment: How can `#define` directives themselves affect code execution speed? They're evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: Preprocessor `#if` conditions should be avoided when possible. Consider what happens if you move the `#define` to other file and forget to include that file? *Condition will fail silently*. Use native conditions or marco wrappers instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one results in less generated code when `flag` is not defined.

Importantly the code that is omitted is the `if` statement, so run time efficiency will also be better because the `if` statement is not unnecessarily being executed `veryBigNumber` times.

Compilers might be able to optimise away the `if` statement by analysing the code, but explicitly "ifdefing" out the code will ensure that it is.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're on a very archaic/dumb compiler, they should be equivalent.
`#if` guarantees evaluation at compile time, however any modern compiler will evaluate a regular `if` with an *integer constant* at compile time too.

---

(In any case, you're only a step away from finding out for yourself.
Just put a very big number in `veryBigNumber` and time each of the two variants. If very big number is really very big (millions, billions) even timing it externally (`time ./a.out` from the command line) should give you fairly reliable timings.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The code below is completely analyzed during compile-time, so `doSomething` will always be executed without any unnecessary cost during runtime. The upper version is expanded at compile-time into the `if` statement; the `if` condition will potentially be evaluated at runtime. However, if code optimization is activated, the compiler might decide that the `if` condition can never be false, hence the entire `if` statement might be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The #define is a precompiler directive. So whatever you write will be analyse and the code inserted.

For example, in your first example the condition will always be true. The compiler will likely just optimise this if() condition out.

Again, with second example this is a "compiler time" test (#if) not a run-time test (if).

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_preprocessors.htm

Performance can be improved by using macros because they help organise your code in a similar way as a function call but the macro code is "inlined" by the compiler. This reduces the overhead of a jump to a location in memory that is required during run-time if a function call is used instead.

They also help make it easier to deal with code that is held constant. This makes your code easier to read and less painful to write (imagine having to remember and insert a constant value every-time you have to use it).

Comment: What do you mean by the last paragraph? What is constant code? What do you mean by "insert a constant value"?

Comment: So in your first example #define flag true. Would mean before compilation the compiler would go through your code and where you've used flag it would substitute with true. Imagine if your line was #define flag 12143, and needed to use that value in multiple places. It would be a pain in the ass having to remember it and write it - easier just write flag. Furthermore, without the macro, when you came back to your code you'd have to try and remember what the value represented. Read the article I linked to, to see how #define can be used for more expressive code too.

Comment: BTW, Nathanial, it is convention (and for good reason) to use uppercase letters for macros, then others will know what it is and where to look to get its definition. So "flag" becomes "FLAG".

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

You should use #ifdef in place of #if defined(flag).(Good Coding Practice)

and code be like:

Define:

```
 #define FLAG
```

Use:

```
#ifdef FLAG
     doSomething1();
#else
    doSomething2();
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks I will do that.